How can I handle a view containing multipage text in React PDF?
I have a vertical box view that has text that needs to span multiple pages. However, the View component appears to size itself correctly, but the Text component inside overflows out of the box into the footer below it. The view itself is tabular, but the issue can be reproduced with a single box:
    import { Document, View, Text, Page, StyleSheet } from "@react-pdf/renderer";

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        header: {border: "1px solid red", height: 50},
        footer: {border: "1px solid red", height: 50},

        box: {
            border: "1px solid black",
            width: 200,
            backgroundColor: "#DDDDDD"
        },
        boxContents: {
            fontSize: 20,
            margin: 5
        }
    });

    const Pdf = () => {
        const text = ` Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vitae 
        tincidunt tortor. Sed nec dolor volutpat, eleifend ante non, interdum mauris. 
        Pellentesque imperdiet mauris non pulvinar porta. Proin dolor nisi, pharetra ac lacus 
        id, elementum iaculis massa. Ut vel fermentum tellus. Sed ultrices, dolor ac semper 
        bibendum, lectus felis interdum arcu, vel dignissim libero dui vitae arcu. Vestibulum 
        ex enim, tempor quis nunc lacinia, aliquam ullamcorper enim. Duis libero tortor, 
        ultrices ac vehicula a, vulputate et nisl. Mauris ullamcorper et lorem a sodales. 
        Mauris congue velit et lorem luctus imperdiet et non dui. Quisque eu porttitor urna. 
        Suspendisse aliquet, eros nec tristique iaculis, odio lacus lacinia arcu, at viverra 
        nunc ligula nec nisl.\r\n\r\n
        
        Quisque accumsan, velit eu ullamcorper sollicitudin, mauris dui tincidunt tellus, eu 
        tempor ex sem ut massa. Praesent ultrices lectus gravida odio semper ultrices. Nulla 
        vestibulum elit eu orci venenatis posuere. Suspendisse congue varius nisl, eget rutrum 
        eros fringilla in. Praesent auctor luctus risus in placerat. Suspendisse vitae 
        scelerisque est, sed tempus odio. Nam aliquet vehicula blandit. Etiam faucibus justo 
        dolor, eu placerat arcu dignissim id. \r\n\r\n
        
        Ut venenatis semper eros eu aliquet. Fusce efficitur arcu diam. Integer sit amet pretium 
        eros. Ut eu sodales felis. Curabitur consectetur, massa non semper iaculis, nisl quam 
        bibendum nunc, eu posuere leo mauris nec tortor. Nullam fringilla mi in sapien malesuada 
        ultrices. Suspendisse malesuada in sem a dictum. Nunc suscipit vulputate lectus ut 
        vehicula. Quisque non tincidunt ligula, ac pulvinar nisl.`;
        return (<Document >
            <Page size="A4">
                <View fixed style={styles.header}></View>
                <View style={styles.box}><Text style={styles.boxContents}>{text}</Text></View>
                <View fixed style={styles.footer}></View>
            </Page>
            </Document>)
    }

    export default Pdf;

This produces unexpected text overflows like this:

This is using React PDF 4.0.0.
How can I create a multipage view containing text, and have the text be laid out within the bounds of the view?
